# Mostrar atributos de un array a traves de un menu en Java

Tags: java, eclipse

En el procedimiento de buscar datos, busco con nombre para mostrar el domicilio, y solo me muestra la primer empresa ingresada, si busco la numero 2 o la 3 me dice que no hay ninguna con ese nombre. alguna idea el porque sucede esto?

**Clase Datos:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Datos 
 {

int contador=0;

    static final int nDatos = 3;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner (System.in);
    char[] cEmpresa = new char[30];
    char[] cDomicilio = new char[40];
    char[] cCod_Postal = new char[30];
    char[] cLocalidad = new char[20];
    char[] cPais = new char[30];
    Datos vector[] = new Datos[nDatos];
    String empresa = new String(cEmpresa);
    String domicilio = new String(cDomicilio);
    String cod_postal = new String(cCod_Postal);
    String localidad = new String(cLocalidad);
    String pais = new String(cPais);

   public Datos(String empresa, String domicilio, String cod_postal, String localidad, String pais){
       super();
       this.empresa = empresa;
       this.domicilio = domicilio;
       this.cod_postal = cod_postal;
       this.localidad = localidad;
       this.pais = pais;
   }


    public Datos() {
    }


    public String getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public String getDomicilio() {
        return domicilio;
    }

    public void setDomicilio(String domicilio) {
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
    }

    public String getCod_postal() {
        return cod_postal;
    }

    public void setCod_postal(String cod_postal) {
        this.cod_postal = cod_postal;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    public String getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(String pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    void Menu() {

        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean salir = false;
        int opcion; //Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

        while (!salir) {

            System.out.println("1. Cargar Empresa");
            System.out.println("2. Listar Empresas");
            System.out.println("3. Buscar Empresa");
            System.out.println("4. Salir");

            try {

                System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
                opcion = sn.nextInt();

                switch (opcion) {
                    case 1:
                        PedirDatos ();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        MostrarDatos();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BuscarDatos();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        salir = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 4");
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Debes insertar un número");
                sn.next();
            }
        }

    }

    void PedirDatos (){

        int opc;

        do  {

            if (contador>=nDatos) {
                System.out.println("Maximas empresas permitidas");
                System.out.println("");
                Menu();
            }
                System.out.println("Empresa:");
                empresa = leer.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Domicilio:");
                domicilio = leer.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Codigo Postal:");
                cod_postal = leer.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Localidad:");
                localidad = leer.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Pais:");
                pais = leer.nextLine();
                vector[contador]= new Datos(empresa, domicilio, cod_postal, localidad, pais);
                contador++;
                System.out.println("Agregar otro usuario");
                opc = leer.nextInt();
                leer.nextLine();

        }while (opc==1);

    }
    void MostrarDatos() {

        for (int i = 0; i<contador; i++) {
            System.out.println("Empresa " + i +": " + vector[i].empresa);
            System.out.println("Domicilio " + i +":" + vector[i].getDomicilio());
            System.out.println("Codigo Postal " + i +":" + vector[i].getCod_postal());
            System.out.println("Localidad " + i +":" + vector[i].getLocalidad());
            System.out.println("Pais " + i +":" + vector[i].getPais());
            if (contador == 1) {
                return;

            }
        }
    }


        void BuscarDatos() {

            Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Nombre a buscar:");
            String nombreAux = leer.nextLine();

                 for(int i = 0 ; i < contador;i++) {

                    if (nombreAux.equals(vector[i].getEmpresa())) {

                            System.out.println(vector[i].getDomicilio()); 
                            break;
                                }

                            else {
                                System.out.println("No hay empresa con ese nombre");
                                Menu();}                                        

                        }

                    }   
                }
```

**Clase Main:**

```
    public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Datos c = new Datos();
        c.Menu();
}

    private static void Menu() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Guillermo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de mostrarnos tu codigo y lo que has intentado hasta ahora con los problmeas concretos que tienes y el resultado esperado. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, sería de ayuda que compartieses tu código para que alguien pueda echarte una mano.

Comment: Java siempre pasa por valor, pero puedes enviar el valor de la dirección de memoria del array - que los ingenieros tuvieron la ocurrencia de llamar referencia -

Comment: desde ya muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta, tengo solamente 585 caracteres para poder insertar el codigo, como hago para poder pasarlo aca ya que el mismo tiene muchos mas caracteres que 585.

Comment: Las preguntas pueden ser modificadas. Edita tu pregunta e inserta el código ahí.

Comment: ahi inserte el codigo, se que esta un poco desprolijo ya que recien estoy comenzando este camino de la programacion en Java, pero la idea de este programa es poder ingresar, en este caso empresas y luego mostrarlas. La opcion de borrar todavia no la genere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Tu ejercicio se puede hacer más corto, fácil y organizado usando ArrayList de tipo Datos para guardar más de una empresa y poder trabajar con ellas. Podrás agregar y remover rápidamente, una pequeña investigación sobre esto te será de ayuda.
2. Por qué tu clase Principal está prácticamente vacía? Deberías tener
       el menú aquí.
3. Por qué cuando haces una instancia de Datos, todos los argumentos
       son `null`? Esto no es una buena práctica, si todos serán `null`
       entonces, simplemente no los pongas y para permitir la instancia de
       la clase Datos, construyes un constructor vacío en dicha clase.
       Seguro podrás investigar qué es un constructor vacío.
4. En la clase Principal tienes un método llamado `Menu()` que no hace
       nada? No sería mejor removerlo?
5. En el constructor que tienes en la clase Datos no estás guardando
           los valores que tienen tus variables. Cuando ingresas los datos de
           la empresa y haces esto `new Datos(empresa, domicilio, .....)`,
           estás haciendo una llamada al constructor de la clase. Luego dentro
           del constructor tienes `empresa ="";` el cual no está haciendo nada,
           simplemente limpiando la variable, es decir, no estás asignando los
           datos de la empresa que solicitaste en ningún lado.
6. En tu método `MostrarDatos()` se te puede presentar el error
   `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Qué pasaría si ingresas solamente
   1 empresa y tratas de Listar Empresas? Aquí aparecerá el error
   mencionado, te muestro a continuación el por qué. Para solucionar esto hay que tener una forma de salir del `for` una vez la primera empresa se haya mostrado, de lo contrario, el error aparecerá y tu programa fallará.

**Método MostrarDatos() incorrecto para mostrar más de 1 empresa**

```
void MostrarDatos() {

// Si solo tenemos 1 empresa, la variable contador = 1

        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Empresa " + i + ": " + vector[i].getEmpresa());
            ..
            ...
            ....
            .....
            // La primera iteración será exitosa pero...
            // En la segunda iteración, es decir, dentro de vector[i + 1]
            // no habrá datos para mostrar y se presentará el error
        }
    }
```

**Método MostrarDatos() correcto para mostrar 2 empresas (una forma rápida de hacerlo)**

```
void MostrarDatos() {

        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Empresa " + i + ": " + vector[i].getEmpresa());
            System.out.println("Domicilio " + i + ":" + vector[i].getDomicilio());
            System.out.println("Codigo Postal " + i + ":" + vector[i].getCod_postal());
            System.out.println("Localidad " + i + ":" + vector[i].getLocalidad());
            System.out.println("Pais " + i + ":" + vector[i].getPais());

            // Si solo hay 1 empresa
            // Salir del for para evitar el error "java.lang.NullPointerException"
            if (contador == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Constructor arreglado para tu clase Datos:**

```
public Datos(String empresa, String domicilio, String cod_postal, String localidad, String pais) {
        super();
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
        this.cod_postal = cod_postal;
        this.localidad = localidad;
        this.pais = pais;
    }
```

Con este cambio en el constructor, se mostrará correctamente los datos de las empresas que ingreses.

**Método BuscarDatos()**

```
void BuscarDatos() {

        boolean encontrada = false;

        do {
            System.out.println("\nNombre de la empresa:");
            String nombre = leer.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {

                // Si la empresa fue encontrada
                if (vector[i].getEmpresa().equals(nombre)) {
                    System.out.println("\nEmpresa encontrada...");
                    System.out.println("Domicilio: " + vector[i].getDomicilio() + "\n");
                    encontrada = true; // Salir del do-while
                    break; // Salir del for
                }
            }

            // Si la empresa no fue encontrada
            if (!encontrada) {
                System.out.println("Empresa no encontrada!\n");
            }

        } while (!encontrada);
    }
```

Con este método llamado BuscarDatos, si tienes las dos empresas podrás buscar cualquiera de ellas por su nombre pero, hay un problema, el mismo que te mencioné anteriormente sobre `NullPointerException`. Si solamente ingresas 1 empresa, a la hora de buscar por su nombre lo va a encontrar correctamente pero, si ingresas un nombre erróneo, el error aparecerá. Para evitar estos errores puedes comprobar antes de entrar al `for` si `vector` tiene información o no y cuánta información tiene, si es 1 empresa o tiene 2.

Como puedes ver, no te soluciono todo el problema ya que realmente arreglarlo es algo bien fácil, solo debes pensar un poco y ese será tu trabajo para que vayas desarrollando lógica.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Robert, cambie el constructor y funciono a la perfeccion. Lo de tener la clase principal vacia, es una costumbre ya que en C hacia un procedimiento para el menu y de ese menu llamaba a los demas procedimientos, masomenos como lo hice en este ejercicio. ArrayList todavia no lo vimos y no me quiero adelantar ya que seria ir salteando pasos, desde ya te agradezco mucho por tu ayuda y por la explicacion que me diste. Un saludo grande

Comment: @GuillermoRubio Me alegro que mi respuesta te haya sido útil. No olvides seleccionarla como Respuesta Elegida y votar por ella también. Un saludo grande, estamos para ayudarnos.

Comment: Robert, en el procedimiento de buscar datos, busco con nombre para mostrar el domicilio, y solo me muestra la primer ingresada, si busco la numero 2 o la 3 me dice que no hay ninguna con ese nombre. Te das una idea el porque sucede esto?

Comment: Realmente no sabría decirte si no veo tu código, debo revisar qué has hecho para detectar tu fallo.

Comment: las demas partes del menu funcionan a la perfeccion, el problema esta al buscar un nombre que no sea el de la posicion [0].

Comment: @GuillermoRubio debo ver tu código para ayudarte. Pega el código en algún sitio web online para compartir código y me pasas el Link para revisarlo ese método que has hecho nuevo.

Comment: ahi edite la pregunta principal y pegue el codigo ahi. Si no lo podes ver avisame que lo reviso o lo subo a gdrive.

Comment: @GuillermoRubio He editado mi respuesta con el código para el método `BuscarDatos()`. Leer el comentario que he dejado debajo del código también. Espero haberte ayudado amigo.